# md5sum failed to open a file, directory issue

Tags: linux, directory, hashsum, checksum

I'm having a problem checking certain `.md5` files, they are all files that are in directories which have been renamed since the files were downloaded.

```
[User1 Directory X]$ md5sum -c file1.txt.md5
md5sum: directoryx/file1.txt: No such file or directory
directoryx/file1.txt: FAILED open or read
md5sum: WARNING: 1 listed file could not be read
```

I noticed the difference in the name of the directory that I am in vs the directory `md5sum` is looking in. The directory was either renamed (not by me!) since the files were downloaded, or the individual files were downloaded to this directory rather than the entire directory being downloaded at once. I edited the directory name to match but this didn't solve the issue.

```
[User1 directoryx]$ md5sum -c file1.txt.md5
md5sum: directoryx/file1.txt: No such file or directory
directoryx/file1.txt: FAILED open or read
md5sum: WARNING: 1 listed file could not be read
```

Any help on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems (from your prompt) that the file is located in the correct `directoryx`, but since `md5sum` will try to read the file at the path given by the `.md5` file, and since you are *in* `directoryx`, it won't find it.

Move one level up in the directory hierarchy and use

```
$ md5sum -c directoryx/file1.txt.md5
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it by opening the md5 file and deleting the original path that pointed to the file.  Or you can add a new path if the target file is in a different location.

```
$ vi file.fastq.tar.gz.md5
```

alphaNumericalKey this/was/original/path/file.fastq.tar.gz

Change the above line to:

alphaNumericalKey file.fastq.tar.gz